# Issues running File replication pro service

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-transfer, tcp, ports

My management server and replication server are both on the same LAN, both have windows 7.

- No firewalls in between
- Windows firewall is also disabled on both machines.
- File replication pro uses port 9100 and port 9200 for file replication and other services.

For some reason this server is not able to communicate with my management server.

I get an error saying:

> could not connect to host : 9200".

When I telnet to this problem server from my management server
`telnet IP_address:9200`, I don't get any ready message, where as I get one from other server which is working fine.

I guess ports 9200 and 9100 are causing this, can anybody please tell me how to open these ports bidirectionally?

Note: Both machines have windows 7 64 bit, they are on same LAN, no firewalls.

Comment: Based on all you say here, there should be nothing to open up though. Try restarting the listening server, confirming with the configs of it that it is indeed the 9200 port or whatever. Telnet into this port from the same localhost machine if you can and see if the screen result is the same when you do it remotely. Make sure the management server service is listening on the port you are connecting to with `netstat -a` or `-ab` on the management server... It's gotta be something being overlooked it the same lan, no firewall and no OS FW in between.

Comment: @DavidPostill - when I do netstat -ab I can see status like, TIME_WAIT, SYN_SENT, OWNERSHIP COULD NOT BE OBTAINED. Yes I restarted the machine many a times, It isnt helping :-(

Comment: @Sam03 Why are you asking me? I just edited the question. You should be asking `@PIMP_JUICE_IT`

Comment: Look at this image here: https://i.imgur.com/vZAruNi.png but I would suspect you should see something with the port 9200 or whatever and it's correlated process name and in the state of listening.